# How to pass data in this format dictonary in array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have tried many solution many times but any them not worked. finally if some one could help that would be really help. I will help you with the  link and format of data need to be passed. You can check how postman to insert code and the below code which I tried. Thanks in advance!

**This below way I insert data by  postman :**

```
insert : 0 
Data :  [{"user_id":"46","e_id":"566","date_list":"2018/04/25","t_depo":" 0.0","mini":"20","real_earn":"-5000.0","mb_balance":"-4000.0","balance_for":"4000"}]
```

**The below code way I tried and I just get response updated successfully but no change in database when I check by postman**

```
var dict = [String : String]()
        dict["user_id"] = "46"
        dict["e_id"] = "566"
        dict["date_list"] = "2018/04/25"
        dict["t_depo"] = " 0.0"
        dict["mini"] = "200"
        dict["real_earn"] = "-5000"
        dict["mb_balance"] = "4000"
        dict["balance_for"] = "4000"
        var dictArray = [dict];

        let parameter: Parameters = [
            "insert" : "0",
            "Data" : dictArray
        ]


        Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON {(response) in
                print(parameter)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try capturing what is being sent using Alamofire, and compare that then to what you're using in Postman? Also you're not handling the error scenario, do that and I'd imagine it will shed some light on the issue:
https://gist.github.com/perlguy99/f7f336b66ccb27fcc148b7d5bdbc9a3f

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your "insert" is of type `int` and you're using a type `string`. Try with

```
    let parameter: Parameters = [
        "insert" : 0,
        "Data" : dictArray
    ]
```

I would also check the `response` object. I believe you should get a status code `201` "Created"